# Result of complex arithmetic in Octave and Python differs

Tags: python, octave, trigonometry, complex-numbers

When I calculate these values, `v` and `w`, in octave and python the output values are very similar, see some outputs below:

```matlab
 v octave values =

 Columns 1 through 3:

          0 - 223.4950i          0 - 194.4942i          0 - 167.4933i

 ...

 Columns 16 through 18:

          0 +        0i     1.4142 +        0i          0 +   2.0000i

 ... 
 Columns 28 through 30:

          0 + 142.4921i          0 + 167.4933i          0 + 194.4942i

 Column 31:

          0 + 223.4950i
```

```py
 v python values 
 [-0.        -223.49496639j -0.        -194.49421585j
 -0.        -167.49328345j -0.        -142.49210504j
...
 -1.41421356  +0.j          0.          +0.j
 ...
  0.        +167.49328345j  0.        +194.49421585j
  0.        +223.49496639j]
```

```matlab
w octave values =

Columns 1 through 4: %before 0

  -4.7124 + 8.5456i  -4.7124 + 8.3371i  -4.7124 + 8.1130i  -4.7124 + 7.8705i

 ...

 Columns 13 through 16:

  -4.7124 + 3.4386i  -4.7124 + 1.6479i  -1.8464 +      0i        0 +      0i

...

 Columns 25 through 28: %after 0

   4.7124 - 6.9950i   4.7124 - 7.3165i   4.7124 - 7.6064i   4.7124 - 7.8705i

 Columns 29 through 31:

   4.7124 - 8.1130i   4.7124 - 8.3371i   4.7124 - 8.5456i
```

```py
w python values 
 [-4.71238898+8.54562334j -4.71238898+8.33714905j -4.71238898+8.11296806j
 ...
  0.        +0.j          1.84643913+0.j          
...
  4.71238898+7.87049456j  4.71238898+8.11296806j  4.71238898+8.33714905j
  4.71238898+8.54562334j]
```

but when I added these values `v + w` and got `z`, `z = v+w`, I got differents outputs values in python and octave.
This it's giving me trouble with the code below.

You can see the outputs for `z = v + w` below:

```matlab
 z = v+w octave values = 

 Columns 1 through 3:

    -4.7124 - 214.9493i    -4.7124 - 186.1571i    -4.7124 - 159.3803i
 ...
 Columns 16 through 18: %after 0

          0 +        0i     3.2607 +        0i     4.7124 +   0.3521i

 Columns 19 through 21:

     4.7124 +   3.9098i     4.7124 +   9.9835i     4.7124 +  18.2866i

 ...
 Columns 28 through 30:

     4.7124 + 134.6216i     4.7124 + 159.3803i     4.7124 + 186.1571i

 Column 31:

     4.7124 + 214.9493i
```

```py
z= v+w python values 
 [-4.71238898-214.94934305j -4.71238898-186.1570668j
 -4.71238898-159.38031539j -4.71238898-134.62161049j
 ...
-3.26065269  +0.j          0.          +0.j
  3.26065269  +0.j          4.71238898  +3.64791843j
 ...
  4.71238898+127.09702398j  4.71238898+150.3625996j
  4.71238898+175.60625151j  4.71238898+202.8313649j
  4.71238898+232.04058972j]
```

Now i share the python/octave codes:

```matlab
%octave code

x = -15:1:15;
E = 3;

p = sqrt(E - x.^2);
v = x.*p;

w = E.*asin(x./sqrt(E));

z = w + v;
```

```py
#python Code
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(-15, 16, 1)
E = 3

p = np.sqrt(E - x.astype(complex)**2)
v = x.astype(complex)*p

w = E*np.arcsin(x.astype(complex)/np.sqrt(E))

z = w + v
```

I don't know what is wrong and can't find information in internet.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: https://floating-point-gui.de/…?

Comment: Please do not use screenshots for text outputs: copy/paste the text in your question instead, with the appropriate formatting. Then your question is unclear. You say that "the output values are very similar", but which values? Do you mean `u` and `v` (trying to guess)? If yes, they are definitely not "similar" on your screenshots, they start differing on the 3rd digit, and the signs are even not the sames.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I already edited my question.
I hope it's clearer my question now.

Comment: There is a different sign for the imaginary component of `w`. This is why the sum differs. The problem might be in the definition of `np.arcsin` vs `asin`.

Comment: I also tried with :
`np.emat.arcsin()` and 
a for loop with `cmath.arcsin()`  

with both I got the same output as `np.arcsin()`.

Comment: Please see [mcve] - you've posted pages of results, when one single result should be sufficient to demonstrate your issue.

Comment: You should dig about the behavior of asin() and np.arcsin(). The inverse sinus has always 2 valid solutions (moreover modulo 2.pi): while there is a widely used convention when the output is real (result between -pi and +pi), this is probably not the case when the output is complex.

Comment: @PierU Indeed, except real-valued arcsin has an infinite number of solutions, not just two: you can add or subtract 2pi to any solution to get another one. The complex-valued one similarly has an infinite number of solutions, an output domain must be chosen. It looks to me that MATLAB and Python have chosen a different domain. It should be trivial to translate the one output to match the other.

Comment: @CrisLuengo that's why I added between parenthesis "modulo 2.pi" ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python `np.arcsin()`and Octave `asin()` behave differently:

```
>>> np.arcsin(0.5)
0.5235987755982988
>>> np.arcsin(2.0+0j)
(1.5707963267948966+1.3169578969248166j)
```

```
>> asin(0.5)
ans =  0.52360
>> asin(2.0)
ans =  1.5708 - 1.3170i
```

When the result is complex, the sign of the imaginary part differ. Both results are correct, it's just that numpy and Octave use different conventions.

Mathematically the inverse sine has an infinity of solutions, numpy and Octave just don't pick the same one.